# Cortex fails to provide all methods on wrapped arrays

Tags: javascript, mquan-cortex

I'm using [Cortex](https://github.com/mquan/cortex) to manage some data that's destined for a React app.

[Cortex's API listing](https://github.com/mquan/cortex#cortex-api) lists some methods that only exist on arrays, namely `filter` and `find`.

Given an object like:

```
var student = {
    schedules: [
        {
            id: 1, year: 2012, semester: 1,
            title: "Schedule 1", sequence: 1,
            clbids: [82908, 82768, 82792, 83505],
            active: true,
        },
        {
            id: 2, year: 2012, semester: 2,
            title: "Schedule 1", sequence: 1,
            clbids: [85898],
            active: true,
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect Cortex to understand that `student.schedules` is an array.

```
cortexStudent = new Cortex(student)
cortexStudent.schedules.__isArray()  // returns `true`
```

Therefore, Cortex would be expected to provide `find` and `filter` methods, right?

```
cortexStudent.schedules.find(function(schedule) {
    return schedule.active.val() === true
})
cortexStudent.schedules.filter(function(schedule) {
    return schedule.active.val() === true
})
```

Nope. `find` works perfectly, but `filter` throws `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`.

Would you agree that this is a bug? I just need someone to double-check me before I report it.

([JSBin w/sample code.](http://jsbin.com/hiyug/5/edit?js,console))

Comment: The minified version of that library does not seem to have been rebuilt after the `.filter()` facility was added. If you load the unminified version into your JSBin, it works.

Comment: Thanks! Good catch. (... except that the new functionality doesn't seem to work in a *different* way. Ah well.)

Comment: No, wait. It **does** work properly. JSBin just prints it weird.

Comment: @Pointy: If you want to put your comment as the answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: OK I will ... I guess it technically is a "bug" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, of a sort, as far as I can tell. The `.filter()` method was added pretty recently, but for whatever reason the minified version of the library was not updated at that time. If you include the un-minified version, the feature seems to work.

It'd probably be nice to log a bug just so the maintainer can fix it; I won't do it because I don't really know anything about the library.